# How can I join data from two custom lists in SharePoint add-ins?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, lookup-column, error, caml-query

I want join 2 custom lists in add-ins:

Data of Lists: `QuanLyMembers.PhongBanId` is `ID` value of `QuanLyPhongBan`

QuanLyPhongBan list:

[image]

QuanLyMembers list:

[image]

This is my code:

```
function getListMem() {
    //var hostWebContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostWebURL);
    var listStatus = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('QuanLyMembers');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Id'/><FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='EmailContact'/><FieldRef Name='PhongBanName'/></ViewFields>" +
        "<Joins><Join Type ='INNER' ListAlias ='QuanLyPhongBan'><Eq><FieldRef Name='PhongBanId' RefType='Id' /><FieldRef List='QuanLyPhongBan' Name='ID' /></Eq>" +
        "<ProjectedFields><Field Name='PhongBanName' Type='Lookup' List='QuanLyPhongBan' ShowField='Title'/> </ProjectedFields></Join>" +
        "</Joins></View>");
    var Items = listStatus.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(Items, 'Include(Title,EmailContact,Id,PhongBanName)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
      
        var oEnumerator = Items.getEnumerator();    
        while (oEnumerator.moveNext()) {           
            var id = oEnumerator.get_current().get_id();
            var title = oEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Title');
            var PhongBanName = oEnumerator.get_current().get_item('PhongBanName ');
            var EmailContact = oEnumerator.get_current().get_item('EmailContact');
           

        }
       

    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

    }));
}
```

But it throws an error:

```
"Value does not fall within the expected range."
```

How can I join data from two custom lists in SharePoint add-ins?

Comment: Why aren't you using [lookup column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632) for this? Using lookup columns will make joining data from two lists easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to create a [lookup column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632) for this.

Create a lookup column in `QuanLyMembers` list referencing to `QuanLyPhongBan` list.

Check below note from Microsoft:

> There are requirements to keep in mind when creating list joins. You cannot join just any two lists, regardless of type. And if two lists can be joined, not just any primary and foreign field can be used as the "join on" pair of fields. **The field in the primary list must be a Lookup type field and it must lookup to the field in the foreign list.** For this reason, all joins mirror existing lookup relations between lists.

**Source**: [List Joins and Projections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539975(v=office.14))

Comment: Because i creating 2 custom list in addins. so I don't know create a lockup column. How can create a lockup column?

Comment: Check this if it helps: [Create list, Column Types, List Instance and List Views in SharePoint Hosted Add-in](https://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/create-list-column-types-list-instance-and-list-views-in-sharepoint-hosted-add-in/).

Comment: Thank you, If I use Lookup Columns, i can get 'get_lookupValue' of Lookup Columns. So will must not use CamlQuery. But When do we use JOIN?

Comment: Yes, if you are using lookup column then I guess no need to use joins in your case. Not completely sure but I think using JOIN will be ideal where you want to join more than two lists, like given in example [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539975(v=office.14)#list-joins-in-views), they are joining five lists.